# Are there examples of good Android Twitter clients?

Tags: java, android, twitter

Are there examples of good Android Twitter clients? I would specifically like to learn how to handle @ clicks etc.

UPDATE:
looking for open source code

Comment: Do you mean the apps as examples or are you looking for example code? I'm quite happy with the way the paid version of TweetCaster works on short and long clicks. If you're looking for sample code for implementing Twitter APIs, I've been happy with the samples I got from commonsware.com as part of my subscription to Mark's books.

Comment: @Eric Cloninger: Note that I have retired the Twitter examples from my books. They hadn't supported Twitter in about a year due to Twitter's switch to OAuth, and my hastily-added identi.ca support was... unreliable.

Comment: @CommonsWare - Guess I should update my e-book files. ;-)  Thx for the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course "good" is very subjective.

[Zwitscher](https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA) is my open source client, that runs on Android and uses the [Twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org) api; a binary version has also been posted to the market.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [sample](http://schwiz.net/blog/2011/using-scribe-with-android/) I made showing how to login with twitter, any other twitter API call would be the same as I do on line 74. As for handling @ click take a look at the [Linkify API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html)